# Does it affect the performance of server if many socket connections are in TIMEWAIT state

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, erlang, scalability

Lets say i have 15000 connections in TIMEWAIT state will it affect the performance in anyway? Problem is I am connecting from erlang to redis and i get redis timeout and I am firing man y queries lets say 15000 in 1-2 seconds.

- Problem is not socket limit

I open connection fire query and close connection that leads many connections in TIMEWAIT state which is ok for me because i have 60k available sockets.

On erlang side I have 20 second timewait which I think is more than sufficient to do the task as redis is very fast.

What can be the problem? BTW I am using eredis as library

Comment: Perhaps google for the *C10K problem*

Comment: What can be what problem exactly? It sounds like you should be using a connection pool at the client.

Comment: Problem is redis returns time out problem.. so if i have 65000 sockets and i am using around 18000 and redis performs well and network speed is good then why timeout? I want to know exactly why timeouts are there whats the bottleneck..

Comment: @Basile.. Thanks i am using erlang cowboy I think it addresses the CK10 problem

Comment: You don't 'have 65000 sockets'. You have 64k *ports,* but all incoming connections use the same port number as the listening socket they connected to, so you can have many times more than 64k sockets. A port in TIME_WAIT state doesn't consume any CPU to speak of. Are you getting connect timeouts or read timeouts?

Answer (score 0):

It will be more efficient not to open connection to redis at your will, but to have a pool of stable connections. You will eliminate significant overhead on starting tcp session each time.
Also you may face a "Too many open files" error.

Consider to tune your `/etc/sysctl.conf` (if you on linux). This params definitely worth to look at:

- net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle
- net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse
- net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout